# What data mining methods can I use for a large (800x100000) matrix that don't require a super computer?

Tags: data-mining

What data mining methods can I use for a large (800x100000) matrix that don't require a super computer?

Because upon trying to do data mining on such data set, even basic PCA in sklearn runs into Memory Error (and I have up to 20GB I think).

How can I do data mining on such large data sets on a home computer?

---

In this case my data is binary.

Comment: Is the data dense or sparse?

Comment: @Sycorax I don't know. How can I discover it from the matrix? Any built-in functions?

Comment: Sparse data is data which is predominantly a particular value. For simplicity, most sparse arithmetic assumes a default value of 0 and only bothers to store nonzero values. In practice, it's often the case that an enormous data matrix is sparse (perhaps because the data matrix represents the occurrences of words in a corpus of documents -- most documents only contain a small number of words, but the union of all English-language documents contains all English words [and many non-English ones!]), which is why I asked.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Do you have a prediction task? Are there $800$ examples or $10^5$ examples?

Comment: @Antoine I want to find out significant variables. 800 samples of 100000 variables each sample.

Comment: @Sycorax I have a binary matrix, so I could perhaps ditch the zeros?

Comment: `sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD` applied to a `scipy.sparse` matrix will give you a projection to a reduced-rank orthogonal basis very efficiently; see any number of [stats.SE] threads about SVD and PCA to understand how the two are very closely related. Just remember to set the number of basis vectors judiciously, since more vectors $\implies$ more computation.

Comment: Note that you have to load the data into a sparse data type to exploit the computational efficiencies of sparse representations.

Comment: @Sycorax https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html Which ones or any? I can't seen anything that compares to np.zeros.

Comment: Read the documentation for the various types. Using sparse matrices is trickier than numpy arrays, because there are trade-offs involved. For example, it's dirt-cheap to update individual elements of a `scipy.sparse.dok` matrix, but it has little, if any, arithmetic support. Once you have data in *some* sparse type, converting to `scipy.sparse.csr` or `csc` should be suitable for `TruncatedSVD`.

Comment: Why not leave the matrix on disk, read subsets of it at a time, and proceed iteratively with whatever "data mining" task you're doing?

Comment: @generic_user You mean doing the analysis on subsets of variables at a time? How can I infer the global phenomena from the subsets then? If the subsets are not allowed to interact?

Comment: Could you elaborate what's not working? Are you having trouble with using sparse types? Or something else?

Comment: @Sycorax I'm having trouble of using data mining methods when the data set is too large to apply the methods directly as in smaller data sets.

Comment: Ok. I guess my question is then "since your data is binary, why are you not using sparse data types?"